# How to extract parameters stored in mock.call

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-3.4

I am unit testing the following functions:

```
import uuid


def process_name(id, name, weight):
    print('process_item:', id, name, weight)


def process_list(names):
    for (name, weight) in names:
        id = uuid.uuid4()
    process_name(id, name, weight)
```

My unit test looks as follows:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, call
import SomePackage.SomeModule


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        items = [('Joe', 190), ('Dan', 200)]
        with patch('SomePackage.SomeModule.process_name') as mock_process_name:
            SomePackage.SomeModule.process_list(items)
```

I cannot match the whole `mock_calls` thing, because the first parameter submitted to it is a guid, and as such it will be different every time I call the function:

```
print(mock_process_name.mock_calls)
[call(UUID('some randomish guid'), 'Joe', 190),
 call(UUID('some other guid'), 'Dan', 200)]
```

I want to extract the parameters, and only match the non-volatile ones:

```
 print(mock_process_name.mock_calls[0][1][1:])
 print(mock_process_name.mock_calls[1][1][1:])
 ('Joe', 190)
 ('Dan', 200)
```

I know that I can also mock the thing which returns guids, and provide a fixed list of values in its side_effect. However, I feel quite lazy needing to mock too many things like `uuid.uuid4()`, `datetime.now()` and such. This is why I am looking for an alternative to mocking each and every volatile function.

Is there a more readable alternative to `mock_calls[0][1][1:]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a proposal to support this use case somewhere (bugs or mock repo?) but AFAIK it's not implemented yet.

For now you have these options in the order of my preference:

#### inspect what you need

```
assert "Joe" in xx.mock_calls[0][1]
assert 190 in xx.mock_calls[0][1]
```

Also has the advantage that when tests break you know exactly which of these two broke.

#### mock UUID

Mock it with predictable sequence and then you can validate your calls.

#### use mock.ANY

```
xx.assert_called_with(mock.ANY, "Dan", 200)
```

Unfortunately only works with the last call.
You could decompose your test.

#### assert_any_call

```
xx.assert_any_call(mock.ANY, "Joe", 190)
```

However you can't validate relative order of Joe and Dan.

#### mock.ANY in roundabout way

```
assert xx.mock_calls[0][1] == (mock.ANY, "Joe", 190)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do your assert is

```
mock_process_name.assert_has_calls([call(ANY, "Dan", 200), call(ANY, "Joe", 190)])
```

Where [`ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) is an helper imported from `mock` module

You can use `any_order=True` options if you are not interested in call order. Moreover if your chain calls is complex you can take a look to [Tracking order of calls and less verbose call assertions](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#tracking-order-of-calls-and-less-verbose-call-assertions).

Comment: That fits very well with OP; Quoting documentation, """ If `any_order` is false (the default) then the calls must be sequential. There can be extra calls before or after the specified calls. """ Gotta remember the last gotcha :)

Comment: @qarma IMHO the name `assert_has_calls` is clear enough to don't forget it (`assert_is_calls` can be a better name for this purpose). I write my `assert_is_calls` helper when I need to check it exactly by use `assert len(m.mock_calls) == len(calls)`